# How to include subdirectories when running a macro in word

Tags: macros, ms-word

I have the following code for a macro. However, it doesn't go through subdirectories. Can anyone tell me how I can edit it so that it does?

```
Sub ChangeTemplates()
Dim strDocPath As String
Dim strTemplateB As String
Dim strCurDoc As String
Dim docCurDoc As Document

' set document folder path and template strings
strDocPath = "C:\Users\servicedesk\Desktop\Test\"
strTemplateB = "C:\Users\servicedesk\Desktop\Blanco.dotx"

' get first doc - only time need to provide file spec
strCurDoc = Dir(strDocPath & "*.doc")

' ready to loop (for as long as file found)
Do While strCurDoc <> ""
    ' open file
    Set docCurDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strDocPath & strCurDoc)
    ' change the template
    docCurDoc.AttachedTemplate = strTemplateB
    ' save and close
    docCurDoc.Close wdSaveChanges
    ' get next file name
    strCurDoc = Dir
Loop
MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your script to extract the part which loops through the files into it's own function, and then call this function recursively whenever a folder is encountered.

The script on [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=76) page demonstrates how to achieve this.